# how to add a string from a file next to a string in another file in unix

Tags: unix

How do I add a string from File2.txt next to `End_Date=` in File1.txt?

File1.txt looks like:

```
Start_Date=29/11/2017 10:15:07
End_Date=
```

And File2.txt looks like:
    29/11/2017 10:20:30

File1.txt should result in:

```
Start_Date=29/11/2017 10:15:07
End_Date=29/11/2017 10:20:30
```

Comment: If you *know* that the both files are exactly one line long *and* you are using Bash you can say `echo "$(< File1.txt)""$(< File2.txt)"`.

Comment: Hi Alex, below is the example of  my files.
File1.txt
Start_Date=29/11/2017 10:15:07
End_Date=
File2.txt
29/11/2017 10:20:30

Comment: Or using PowerShell with `Get-Content "File2.txt" | Add-Content "File1.txt" -NoNewLine`

Comment: It doesn't work too!